# One specific SVG not showing up in the production version of my React app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

So I tried using a star svg as rating for my react project and it seems to work in development but when I deployed it to Heroku, the star svg seems to be acting up and not working as expected. I took this star svg from [heroicons.dev](https://heroicons.dev)

[Star svg in development Card.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wn46.png)

But as soon as I go in heroku version, I get this
[Star svg in production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoEFl.png)

Here is the same star svg which is used for another page but star svg is not having the same look as the dev build
[Dev Build star svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REHLK.png)
[Production Build star svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Nlw.png)

[All other svgs work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bKc0.png)
Here is the code for svg

```
<svg class="w-6 h-6 bg-yellow-500 p-0.5 rounded-sm" fill="white"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z"></path></svg>
```

Here is the code for Card.js [Production Build]

```
<div className=" px-1 py-4 w-full text-center">
                <div className="font-bold text-xl mb-2">{props.restaurantName}</div>
                <div className="grid grid-cols-2">
                    <div className="flex flex-col">
                        <div className="col-span-1 flex items-center gap-2  text-center">
                            <div className="text-white">
                                <StarIcon />
                            </div>
                            {props.overallRating.$numberDecimal}
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex text-gray-500 uppercase text-xs text-center">
                            Rating
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-span-1 text-center ">
                        ₹ {props.costForTwo}
                        <h2 className="text-gray-500 uppercase text-xs">Cost For Two</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Card.svg [Dev build]

```
<div className=" px-1 py-4 w-full text-center">
                <div className="font-bold text-xl mb-2">{props.restaurantName}</div>
                <div className="grid grid-cols-2">
                    <div className="flex flex-col">
                        <div className="col-span-1 flex items-center gap-2  text-center">
                            <div className="text-white">
                                <StarIcon />
                            </div>
                            {props.overallRating.$numberDecimal}
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex text-gray-500 uppercase text-xs text-center">
                            Rating
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-span-1 text-center ">
                        ₹ {props.costForTwo}
                        <h2 className="text-gray-500 uppercase text-xs">Cost For Two</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I'll be glad if I found a fix for this.

EDIT:[HTML shown in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hche.png)

Comment: Can you open the generated HTML in browser inspector to see how your icon is loaded on the client side?

Comment: Yeah sure I'll add that in the question
EDIT: Ok so something weird happened, I tried changing CSS in HTML browser and somehow it appeared but on reload it disappears

Comment: OK I just changed some css like from bg-yellow-500 to bg-yellow-400 and it worked!